# javascript: add html to end of <span> (noob)

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am sure there must be an easier way that doing this:

```
foo.innerHTML +="<br>";
```

The above is producing dirty results as there is a textbox in the SPAN and the data from that textbox gets wiped away when using innerHTML.

I am trying to "re-learn" JS so forgive me if the question is too noobish.

Comment: Pls show your html too.

Comment: try using  `appendChild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the neatest way to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) a new HTML-Element to another:

**HTML**

```
<span id="mySpan">This is my Text</span>
```

**JS**

```
var span = document.getElementById('mySpan');
var br = document.createElement('br');
span.appendChild(br);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `var br = document.createElement("br"); foo.appendChild(br);`

Comment: This won't work. `appendChild` needs a node as parameter not a string.

Comment: it works but I get this error: Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.

Comment: Thanks,  while you were editing I tried Alex's answer and it worked... i'm upvoting both of you though :)